# Determine if any value in Sheet1, Column A, matches any value in each row of Sheet2

Tags: excel, vba, match

I'm trying to determine if any of the codes from Sheet1 Column A exist in each row of names in Sheet2, each of which have as many as 24 columns.

I do not need to know every match, just a logical yes/no for each row, if a match is found on any value in the column.

Answer (score 1):

No need for VBA. Just put this formula in Sheet1!B2 and fill down or double-click the 'fill handle'.

```
=if(isnumber(match(a2, sheet2!$1:$1, 0)), "yes", "no")
```

If you absolutely require VBA then,

```
sub isitthere()
    with worksheets("sheet1")
        with .range(.cells(2, "B"), .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).offset(0, 1))
            .formula = "=if(isnumber(match(a2, sheet2!$1:$1, 0)), ""yes"", ""no"")"
            .value = value
        .end with
    end with
end sub
```

Comment: If I understand your formula correctly, it would return "yes" or "no" depending on whether the value in A2 was present in any of the rows (and the next row the value in A3, etc.)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. That is how I understood your request.

Comment: I don't think this will solve my problem.  I need something that will compare all values in Sheet1 Column A with the values populated in the particular columns of Sheet2 Row 1 determine if any match.  I need to do this for each individual Row in Sheet2, and determine if there is a match for every row.

Comment: No worries. Good to hear you got sorted out.

Comment: Actually, I haven't gotten it sorted out.  I still don't have an answer of how to do the comparison I'm trying to do between the column and the rows on the other sheet.